# JSP is not retrieving the text field value

Tags: jsp

I am writing a simple JSP code that should take a textbox value, form a sql, execute and return the result to another text field. I get an empty result. The following is my code.

The driver is working and value is set if no condition in the statement like selecting first name `if rownum<1` for example, so I am sure it is registered fine.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Holiday Master</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %> 
<div>

        <input id="input1" name="Text1" type="text"><input id="input2" name="Text2" type="text"><input name="Button1" onclick="get_data()" type="button" value="button"></div>
```

```javascript
<script>
function get_data()
{
<%
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","hr");
    Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
    String sql2 = request.getParameter("input1"); 
    String sql="select last_name from employees where first_name ='"+sql2+"'";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    try
    {
    if(rs!=null)
    {

    while(rs.next())
    {
    %>

   document.getElementById("input2").value="<%=rs.getString("last_name")%>";    

    <%
    }
    }        
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stmt.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();
    stmt=null;
    rs=null;
    conn=null;
    %>



}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different codes. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: So as i understand from your reply that
document.getElementById("input2").value<%=rs.getString("last_name")%>";
will not understand what rs means because it executes server side ? so how do you suggest i fill the text box with the query result ?

Comment: The problem begins even earlier, the `sql2` string is `null` on the first call of the page, so (IMHO) the whole query should fail. (Btw. `request.getParameter(String parameterName)` expects `name` of the input attribute as `parameterName`, not its `id`.) You need AJAX for what you want to achieve, see e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/3511123) for a brief introduction.

Comment: And btw. **never ever** compose SQL statements by concatenating the strings. Learn to use `PreparedStatement`s. Reason: [SQL Injection](http://www.royabubakar.com/blog/2014/01/19/sql-injection-in-java-web-application/) - i.e. what if I enter into your first input field something like `'; drop table employees; --`? ;-)